# Can the bias of a dense layer be set to zero in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to implement a neural network in which I need the kernel multiplication with the input only. The dense layer in Tensorflow also adds bias which I am trying to set to zero. From the documentation the only variable that is available to play with is `bias_regularizer`. So I tried doing the following:

```py
def make_zero(_):
    return np.zeros(21,)

out1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=codeword, units=21, activation=None, bias_regularizer=make_zero)
```

But I still see the bias values are not zero. Is there any other method to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the documentation of [`tf.layers.dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense), you can use the option `use_bias=False` to remove the bias altogether:

```
out1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=codeword, units=21, activation=None, use_bias=False)
```

Comment: What are downside of not training bias term?

Comment: @haneulkim You can think of the bias as the intercept term in linear regression. Having a bias term makes it easy to learn a mapping that is "shifted" from zero. For example, if you have pairs of _x_ and _y_ like (1, 1010), (2, 1020), (5, 1050), ... it is trivial to model it as _y_ = 10 * _x_ + 1000, but if you didn't have a bias / intercept you'd have a hard time fitting that. In neural networks, if the optimal value of a unit is always between 0.85 and 0.95 it is easier to have a bias of 0.9 and use the weights to calculate the remaining variance.